# Display certain data from RealTime Database for the current user using uid

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have tried many ways including rearrange the child location but still didnt work. I want to display BMI from realtime database using uid at the homepage but the value at the text view still null. Anyone please help me since I am still new in firebase.

Extra information : The BMI Value is calculated from the previous activity.

[image: this is my structure from firebase]

[my current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrbll.png)

[what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yD0mt.jpg)

this is HomePage Activity:

```
public class HomepageUser extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView showBMI;
DatabaseReference myRef;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage_user);
    showBMI = ( TextView) findViewById(R.id.showBMI);

    //Database
    //FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("bmi");

}
// Read from the database

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String finalBmi = (String)dataSnapshot.child("bmi").getValue();
            showBMI.setText( ("BMI:   " + finalBmi));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

This is code of the previous activity:

```
private void updateBMI(double bmi, final FirebaseUser currentUser) {

    kg = Double.parseDouble(inputKg.getText().toString());
    m = Double.parseDouble(inputM.getText().toString());


    metricFormula = new MetricFormula(kg, m);
    imperialFormula = new ImperialFormula(kg, m);

    //bmi = String.valueOf(TWO_DECIMAL_PLACES.format(metricFormula.computeBMI(metricFormula.getInputKg(),metricFormula.getInputM())));
    bmi = Double.parseDouble(TWO_DECIMAL_PLACES.format(metricFormula.computeBMI(metricFormula.getInputKg(),metricFormula.getInputM())));

    final double finalBmi = bmi;

    mAuth.updateCurrentUser(currentUser).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

            UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdate = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                    .build();

            currentUser.updateProfile(profileUpdate)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){

                                Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
                                values.put("bmi", finalBmi);

                                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                                        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                        .updateChildren(values).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            //acc successfully registered
                                            showMessage("Account Updated");

                                            updateUI();
                                        }
                                        else{
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    });

}

//next page
private void updateUI() {

    Intent homepageActivity = new Intent(EditProfileActivity.this,HomepageUser.class);
    //homepageActivity.putExtra("bmi",bmi); //new
    startActivity(homepageActivity);
    finish();

}
```

I have tried many ways but still didnt work.

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Comment: thanks a lot sir for the respond, I will try it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attaching a listener to:

```
myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("bmi");
```

So `/Users/$uid/bmi`. Then you read the value with:

```
myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String finalBmi = (String)dataSnapshot.child("bmi").getValue();
        showBMI.setText( ("BMI:   " + finalBmi));
    }
```

So at this point you're reading `/Users/$uid/bmi/bmi`, which does not exist.

To fix this, remove the `child("bmi")` from `onDataChange`:

```
myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String finalBmi = (String)dataSnapshot.getValue();
        showBMI.setText( ("BMI:   " + finalBmi));
    }
```

Comment: If the app crashes, there is an exception that gets logged. Find it in your logcat output, and add the complete message and stack trace to your question.

Comment: sir, actually i have figured out the problem, because I have tried with the other child class like email, weight etc, the other child works but not for bmi. I think it have something to do with my previous activity

Comment: You might have more problems in your code, but the one in my answer is definitely one problem. To allow us to efficiently help you, please for future questions ensure that you share the minimum code to reproduce a single problem. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

This happening because I attach double infos for child /Users/$uid/bmi/bmi, which should be /Users/$uid/bmi

and note that set text view cant string double unless you assign them like this

String bmi = (String) Double.toString((Double) dataSnapshot.getValue());
                showBMI.setText( ("BMI:   " + bmi));